# Custom Wall at Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

is it possible to have something like this in a simple manor without loosing any sort of functionality from the ordinary wall? (doing just a comment section within an iframe isn't  what i mean...).

**Example:**

[image: Facebook Custom Wall]

I do understand that one can't have that under "Wall" but need to create a separat "tab" for it. I'm just leaning for it to be the same as the wall but with my own small addon.

Is there any examples of somthing very similar or an example of someone including a *real* wall with all functionalities etc?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would have to create a Page Tab app.    It will take a lot of work to recreate the wall layout via the API calls, but it can be done. To get wall postings you just HTTP GET `me/home` via the Graph API using a page access token.  There's a lot to learn, so take it slowly in managable steps.
Here's a jQuery example of recreating the wall:

http://tutorialzine.com/2011/03/custom-facebook-wall-jquery-graph/

Comment: Recreating something that looks like the Wall but has another part at the top would be in violation of policy; it's also not possible to remove the actual wall, so i'm not sure what good it would do having a second 'wall'-esque tab

Comment: They said they'd leave in the Wall and have a page tab that functions similar to the wall.  They're not trying to update the existing functionality or obscure it "*I do understand that one can't have that under "Wall" but need to create a separat "tab" for it. I'm just leaning for it to be the same as the wall but with my own small addon.*"